# Could not get value. Returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have tried to use the get method before using a frame for the label and buttons. But after using the frame, it always returns a attribute error.

I've already tried this piece of code without a frame and it returns perfectly.

```
root = Tk()
head = Label(root, text='LOGIN', font=('', 35), pady=10)
head.pack()
logf = Frame(root, padx=90, pady=90)
Label(logf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
e1 = Entry(logf, bd=5, font=('Calibri', 15)).grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(logf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(logf, bd=5, font=('Calibri', 15), show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(logf, text=' Quit ', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=root.quit).grid()
Button(logf, text=' Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=update).grid(row=2,column=1)
logf.pack()
username=("%s"%((e1.get())))
password=("%s"%((e2.get())))
```

I should get the value of username and password in the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put .grid() on the next line.

```
root = Tk()
head = Label(root, text='LOGIN', font=('', 35), pady=10)
head.pack()
logf = Frame(root, padx=90, pady=90)
Label(logf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
e1 = Entry(logf, bd=5, font=('Calibri', 15))
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(logf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(logf, bd=5, font=('Calibri', 15), show='*')
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(logf, text=' Quit ', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=root.quit).grid()
Button(logf, text=' Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=update).grid(row=2,column=1)
logf.pack()
username=("%s"%((e1.get())))
password=("%s"%((e2.get())))
```

---

This:

```
e2 = Entry(logf, bd=5, font=('Calibri', 15), show='*').grid(row=1,   column=1)
```

Sets e2 to the return value of .grid(), which is nothing. This doesnt create an entry field variable/reference at all. This means you will not be able to get the value of the entry field later on using e2.get() because the e2 reference doesnt exist.

This:

```
e2 = Entry(logf, bd=5, font=('Calibri', 15), show='*')
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Creates the e2 variable/reference. This creates the entry in a way where you will be able to get the value in the entry field using e2.get().

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did the job.